# MariaDB - PHP - Data not being inserted into the table when the Form is submitted

Tags: php, html, sql, mariadb

I'm very new to PHP so please bear with me. I have a registration form and I'm submitting the values entered on that form and having them inserted into a Maria Database table, but the data is not being inserted into the table.

I did a select * from profileinformation; on the table and the data isn't there.

Any help is appreciated and points will be awarded!

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>Registration Page</title>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["netID"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("NetID must be filled out");
    return false;
    }

    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("Email must be filled out");
    return false;
    }

    var n = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (n == null || n == "") {
    alert("First Name cannot be blank");
    return false;
    } else if (n.length < 2) {
        alert("First name cannot be less than 2 characters!");
        return false;
    }

    var b = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
    if (b == null || b == "") {
    alert("Last Name cannot be blank");
    return false;
    } else if (b.length < 2) {
        alert("Last Name cannot b less than 2 characters!");
        return false;

    }

}

</script>



</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <center><img src="KSUlogo.PNG" alt="logo" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a class="active" href="Welcome.html">Home</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a href="CSERegistrationPage.html">Registration</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a href="#contact">Search</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</ul>


<h1 style="text-align:center;">CCSE Community Profile Page</h1>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<h2 style="text-align:center;">Enter your Registration Information</h2>

<div style="text-align:center">

<form name="myForm" action="RegistrationValues.php" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<center>NetID: <input type="text" name="netID"></center>
<br>
<center>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></center>
<br>
<center>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"></center>
<br>
<center>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"></center>
<br>
<br>
Services You Can Provide the CSE Community</center><br>
<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="Java"> Java Tutoring<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="Computer" checked> Computer Fixing<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="radio" value="PHP" checked> PHP Tutoring<br>
<br><br>
<select name="availabilty">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="Java">Morning</option>
    <option value="Computer">Evening</option>
    <option value="Service">Afternoon</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
</form>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>Registration Page</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php include "header.html";?>
<?php include "navigation.html";?>

<div style="text-align:center">

<p>netID: <?php echo $_POST["netID"]?></p>

<p>Email: <?php echo $_POST["email"]?></p>

<p>First Name <?php echo $_POST["fname"]?></p>

<p>Last Name: <?php echo $_POST["lname"]?></p>

<?php

$netID = $email = $fname = $lname = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $netID = test_input($_POST["netID"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
  $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "newpassword";
$dbname = "project";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$conn->query("insert into ProfileInformation (netID, email, fname, lname, radio, availabilty) 
                values
            ( '{$_POST['netID']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['fname']}', '{$_POST['lname']}', '{$_POST['radio']}', '{$_POST['availabilty']}' )") or die(mysql_error());

            echo "Done!!!!";

$conn->close();
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the PHP file echo "done"?

Comment: No it does not and thanks. It also does not show the values that I selected from the checkboxes and drop down menu. It does show everything that I entered in the textboxes on the html page on the php page

Comment: If the problem's not solved, please look into what it echoes and you'll find your error :)

Comment: Thanks. Please help me find this error because I'm at a loss right now

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could edit your question and add what your php file echoes, apart from the header and navigation

Comment: add `return true;` at the end of function `validateForm`

Comment: Done! I added return true at the end of ValidateForm

Comment: The page doesn't echo anything. That is the Problem.
I tried to add a screen shot but I was unable to

Comment: i tested the form and it works.. the php receive post as it shoud.. so problem will be maybe in `<?php include "header.html";?><?php include "navigation.html";?>` which hide your echos

Comment: btw you should use mysqli prepared statements, because now you are vulnerable to sql injection and its not related to using post instead of `test_input` sanitized variables in query

Comment: Thanks for all your help but it is not inserting the data into the database. Any thoughts?

Comment: are the post printed ?

Comment: Please explain what post printed means?

Comment: if `<p>netID: <?php echo $_POST["netID"]?></p>` etc.. are shown at output

Comment: Thanks and yes they are shown as the output

Comment: you mixin procedural and OO style, try: `if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conn->connect_error);
}` insead of `if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}`

Comment: What's inside radio and availabilty? Look at that output. Maybe they can't be saved in the DB as they are posted.

Comment: I'm now getting 


Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\IndividualProject\RegistrationValues.php on line 52

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\IndividualProject\RegistrationValues.php on line 52

Comment: and `$conn->query` didnt die ever..

Comment: @stefan You are right I changed my variables but still the data did not insert into the database

Comment: use `if(!$conn->query()){ echo "Invalid query: ".$conn->error; }`

Comment: Now I got


Warning: mysqli::query() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\IndividualProject\RegistrationValues.php on line 52
Invalid query:

Comment: you need to put query inside...

Comment: You can use json_encode to convert the array to a json string. Than you should be able to store it into the DB. But that's just one example how you can handle this. For security reason, don't use directly the POST variables within the query. Use the variables you have after you applied the test_input function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(!$conn->query("insert into ProfileInformation (netID, email, fname, lname, radio, availabilty) 
                values
            ( '{$_POST['netID']}', '{$_POST['email']}', '{$_POST['fname']}', '{$_POST['lname']}', '{$_POST['radio']}', '{$_POST['availabilty']}' )")){
    echo "Invalid query: ".$conn->error;
}else{
    echo "Done!!!!";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! You are the PHP Guru!